# Can I trigger both form-methods get & post by clicking one button?

Tags: php, html

I have download button, that is supposed to download a file and to run a php-script.

This is the download part:

```
<form method="get" action="download/setup.exe">         
    <button type="submit" name="download">DOWNLOAD 83,5MB</button>
</form>
```

This is the "script-run" part:

```
<form action="includes/dbupdate.inc.php" method="post">             
    <button type="submit" name="download">DOWNLOAD 83,5MB</button>
</form>
```

How can I combine both? If I put them into each other, only the outer/first form will be triggered. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple JS (JavaScript) script on the OnClick attribute as follow to open more tabs.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) is a guide of this JS method.

```
<button name="download" onclick="window.open('download/setup.exe'); window.open('includes/dbupdate.inc.php');">DOWNLOAD 83,5MB</button>
```

Or you can perform multiple actions by using the `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('download/setup.exe'); window.open('includes/dbupdate.inc.php');">
    <button name="download">DOWNLOAD 83,5MB</button>
</a>
```